# webdrivererror: Connection reset

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

This is what i am getting in console
nothing change in npm or in code ,nothing found on internet related to this issue

```
[14:29:48] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[14:29:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:29:50] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.80.132:49611/wd/hub

D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
         ^
WebDriverError: Connection reset
    at WebDriverError (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27:10)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\erro
r.js:580:13)
    at D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\pro
mise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.
js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\prom
ise.js:2773:21)
    at D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27
    at D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js
:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webd
river.js:295:12)
    at Builder.build (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24
)
    at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverP
rovider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:182:43)
    at D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:255:30
    at _fulfilled (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\Workspace\pen\content\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
[14:29:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
```

Comment: Is this only for a local run or only from Jenkins?

Comment: it is on local run, got https://github.com/aullman/opentok-meet/issues/142 is seems related to this , but can't figure out the solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 

This issue was fix in a updated version

Comment: My issue was I had a globally installed version of protractor and `webdriver-manager update` was only updating the local install.

Comment: try to update protractor globally webdriver will update automatically